# While fetching data from 3 tables using join I get an error: Column 'semester' and 'department' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, pdo

**All three table contains 'semester' and 'department' column**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
  test_name,
  fname,
  lname,
  rno 
FROM exam_attempted_list
INNER JOIN stud_test ON
  exam_attempted_list.student_id = stud_test.student_id
INNER JOIN stud_reg ON
  exam_attempted_list.student_id = stud_reg.student_id WHERE semester='2nd' AND department='cse'
```

Comment: Use table aliases.

Comment: You will have to name each table such as : `FROM exam_attempted_list AS eal` then use `eal.semester`, that way MySQL will understand which table it should retrieve information from.

Comment: @Trukken sir it does not work its show error semester field ambigious

Comment: @Trukken SELECT DISTINCT test_name ,fname, lname ,rno , semester FROM exam_attempted_list AS e INNER JOIN stud_test AS st ON e.student_id = st.student_id INNER JOIN stud_reg AS r ON e.semester = r.semester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use table aliase like ***exam_attempted_list.semester***='2nd'

```
SELECT DISTINCT test_name ,fname, lname ,rno
FROM
exam_attempted_list 
INNER JOIN stud_test ON exam_attempted_list.student_id = stud_test.student_id
INNER JOIN stud_reg ON exam_attempted_list.student_id = stud_reg.student_id
WHERE exam_attempted_list.semester='2nd' AND exam_attempted_list.department='cse';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format, i.e, there were some statements which were repeating in your query, missing aliases in statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT exam_attempted_list.test_name ,exam_attempted_list.fname, 
exam_attempted_list.lname , exam_attempted_list.rno
FROM exam_attempted_list
INNER JOIN stud_test 
ON exam_attempted_list.student_id = stud_test.student_id
INNER JOIN stud_reg 
ON exam_attempted_list.student_id = stud_reg.student_id 
WHERE semester='2nd' AND department='cse'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT eal.test_name , eal.fname, eal.lname , eal.rno 
FROM exam_attempted_list AS eal 
INNER JOIN stud_test AS st ON eal.student_id = st.student_id 
INNER JOIN stud_reg AS sr ON eal.student_id = sr.student_id 
WHERE eal.semester='2nd' AND eal.department='cse'
```

Replace `eal` with either `st` or `sr` depending on where you want the data from.